# Stacked area chart only display dot (R)

Tags: r, dataframe, graph, stacked-area-chart

I m trying to make a stacked area chart, but my chart is not 'fill', instead there is just dots.

My output:

[image]

My code:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x=avg_time, y=value, fill=Attrition)) + 
    geom_area()
```

My dataframe :

```
             avg_time    Attrition    value
              <dbl>        <chr>       <dbl>
 1            7.4            No          1  
 2            7.7           Yes          1  
 3            7.0            No          1  
 4            7.2            No          1  
 5            8.0            No          1
```

Sample of my dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(structure(list(avg = c(7.4, 7.7, 7, 7.2, 8, 11, 6.9, 6.7, 7.2, 
7.1, 8.4, 7.1, 9.3, 9.4, 6.1, 6.7, 6.6, 11, 7, 9.3, 7.6, 6, 8.4, 
6.8, 7.1), Attrition = c("No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), value = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 25L), class = "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Can you provide a bigger sample of your data? It might be that your data is not a good fit for a stacked bar plot though.

Comment: Hard to replicate your issue with the sample data provided. But my guess is that you have multiple obs per avg_time. In that case you could try with `stat_summary(fun = "sum", geom = "area", position = "stack")` instead of `geom_area`.

Comment: While your data make it hard to reproduce the issue (see @Till and @stefans) comments, I think to remember that sorting the data on the x-component before plotting helps. In your case that'd be: `df %>% arrange(avg_time) %>% plot stuff`

Comment: @Till I provide a bigger sample of my dataframe, and you are right when I reduce the size of my dataframe the chart is displayed correctly.

Comment: @stefan Yes there is multple obs per average time. Your solution is working too ! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the solution of @stefan:

```
ggplot(df_graph, aes(x=avg, y=value, fill=Attrition)) + 
    stat_summary(fun = "sum", geom = "area", position = "stack")
```

[image]